# Order of a cyclic group?

Tags: cyclic-groups

When finding the order of a cyclic group, do we determine so by counting the number of elements in that group generator by the cyclic group?

Comment: The order of any group is the number of elements in the group.

Comment: For any finite group (cyclic or otherwise) the order of the group is the number of elements in that group.

Comment: @AnuragA the group does not have to be finite.

Comment: @Mr.Fry the reason I added finite was because OP was using the term "counting the number" of elements which would  make more sense in a finite setting.

Comment: There are sets which are countably infinite. So counting make sense outside of the finite case. There would be confusion for the OP seeing your reply and Cameron's.

Answer (score 0):

The order of any group is the number of elements in the group. Same holds for cyclic groups. Since moreover cyclic groups have a generator say $x$. Then the order of this cyclic group will be the order of $x$.